# Error in calculation of inbuilt MS-SSIm function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
t1=tf.image.ssim_multiscale(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test1[i]),tf.convert_to_tensor(ans1[i]),max_val=1).eval()
file1.write("\tMs-ssim:\t"+str(t1)+"\n")
avgs+=ssim1
avgm+=t1
print(t1)
print(i)

file1.write("MS-SSIM:\t"+str(avgm/100))
```

When ms-ssim is calculated, its showing the following error, however everything seems to be correct, there are 2 numpy arrays, among which we are doing comparision of MS-SSIM, 
ans1[i] and x_test1[i] are two arrays in numpy
I have calcualted the psnr and ssim using the same inbuilt functions in tensorflow which takes same numpy arrays of inputs to be compared, but the same concept is giving the following error for MS-SSIM

**The error is following**

```
      0.5862568
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call     last)
 ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client    / session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
  -> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

   ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client   /session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options,     run_metadata)
      1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
  -> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,     run_metadata)
    1320 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client    /session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,     target_list, run_metadata)
    1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,   target_list,
 -> 1407         run_metadata)
    1408 

      **InvalidArgumentError: Computed output size would be negative: -2     [input_size: 8, effective_filter_size: 11, stride: 1]
 [[{{node MS-SSIM_2/Scale4/depthwise_1}}]]**

      During handling of the above exception, another exception   occurred:

        InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most     recent call last)
 <ipython-input-150-850d3da2c004> in <module>()
             12                  t=tf.image.psnr(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test1[i]),tf.convert_to_tensor(ans1[   i]),max_val=1).eval()
             13     file1.write("\tPSNR:\t"+str(t))
          ---> 14               t1=tf.image.ssim_multiscale(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test1[i]),tf.convert_to_ tensor(ans1[i]),max_val=2).eval()
            15     file1.write("\tMs-ssim:\t"+str(t1)+"\n")
            16     avgs+=ssim1

          ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python /framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
          693 
           694     """
        --> 695     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
             696 
            697 

           ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
           5179                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
        5180                        "graph.")
          -> 5181   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
          5182 
       5183 

           ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
           927     try:
         928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
     --> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
       930       if run_metadata:
       931         proto_data =    tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

  ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options,  run_metadata)
    1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and     feed_dict_tensor):
         1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets,  final_fetches,
       -> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options,      run_metadata)
    1153     else:
         1154       results = []

           ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
      1326     if handle is None:
         1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
        -> 1328                            run_metadata)
     1329     else:
            1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds,   fetches)

      ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
      1346           pass
         1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
      -> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
           1349 
       1350   def _extend_graph(self):

     InvalidArgumentError: Computed output size would be negative: -2  [input_size: 8, effective_filter_size: 11, stride: 1]
        [[node MS-SSIM_2/Scale4/depthwise_1 (defined at <ipython-input-      150-850d3da2c004>:14) ]]

         Caused by op 'MS-SSIM_2/Scale4/depthwise_1', defined at:
         File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193,       in _run_module_as_main
         "__main__", mod_spec)
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
                  exec(code, run_globals)
        File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages   /ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
           app.launch_new_instance()
             File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
           app.start()
         File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages /ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
          ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages /zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
       super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages  /tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
          handler_func(fd_obj, events)
        File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado    /stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
         File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages /zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
       self._handle_recv()
       File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/        zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
       self._run_callback(callback, msg)
       File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/z mq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
         callback(*args, **kwargs)
         File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages /tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
         return fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/        ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
           return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
           File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages  /ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
          handler(stream, idents, msg)
    File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/k         ernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
       user_expressions, allow_stdin)
      File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel    /ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history,  silent=silent)
      File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel /zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
        return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
       File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython /core/interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
          raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
        File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython /core/interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
         interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
       File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/ core/interactiveshell.py", line 2901, in run_ast_nodes
           if self.run_code(code, result):
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
     File "<ipython-input-150-850d3da2c004>", line 14, in <module>
     t1=tf.image.ssim_multiscale(tf.convert_to_tensor(x_test1[i]),tf.convert_to_ tensor(ans1[i]),max_val=2).eval()
        File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages   /tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py", line 2867, in ssim_multiscale
         ssim_per_channel, cs = _ssim_per_channel(*imgs,      max_val=max_val)
         File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages  /tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py", line 2700, in _ssim_per_channel
           luminance, cs = _ssim_helper(img1, img2, reducer, max_val,  compensation)
         File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages   /tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py", line 2610, in _ssim_helper
               mean1 = reducer(y)
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages         /tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py", line 2696, in reducer
                      y = nn.depthwise_conv2d(x, kernel, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], p     adding='VALID')
                  File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 522, in depthwise_conv2d
           op=op)
             File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 435, in with_space_to_batch
              return new_op(input, None)
                   File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 591, in __call__
               return self.call(inp, filter)
            File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 425, in <lambda>
             return lambda inp, _: op(inp, num_spatial_dims, padding)
             File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages /tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py", line 514, in op
   name=name)
           File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages /tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 2251, in  depthwise_conv2d_native
             dilations=dilations, name=name)
            File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages   /tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in     _apply_op_helper
         op_def=op_def)
             File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages          /tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
          return func(*args, **kwargs)
          File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
            op_def=op_def)
              File "/home/dipti/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__
           self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

              **InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Computed output size would be negative: -2 [input_size: 8, effective_filter_size: 11, stride: 1]
            [[node MS-SSIM_2/Scale4/depthwise_1 (defined at <ipython-input-150-850d3da2c004>:14) ]]**
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be with assertion after spatial-dimension reduction. In  `_ssim_per_channel`, the `H` and `W` of images is [asserted](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L3524) against `filter_size` . Whereas in `ssim_multiscale`, [downsampling](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L3741) is performed `len(power_factors)-1` times.

Here are two workarounds:

1. Make sure that `filter_size` is small enough to calculate ssim values for all the four spatial-scales(excluding first scale) after downsampling within `ssim_multiscale`. Contrarily, ensure both `H` and `W` of your image are big enough such that `H/(2**4) and W/(2**4) >= filter_size` .
2. Since downsampling is performed `len(power_factors)-1` times, you can also use lesser number of `_MSSSIM_WEIGHTS` or power_factors than default, which means `H/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)) and W/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)) >= filter_size` .

```py
field1 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, 64, 64, 1], minval=0, maxval=1)
field2 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, 64, 64, 1], minval=0, maxval=1) 
#Use smaller filter_size
ms_ssim_score = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(img1=field1, img2=field2, max_val=1.0,
                                         filter_size=4)
#Or use lesser number of power_factors
ms_ssim_score = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(img1=field1, img2=field2, max_val=1.0,
                                         power_factors=(0.0448, 0.2856, 0.3001),
                                         filter_size=11)
```

You can use try obtaining a suitable value of `filter_size` with:

```py
def suggest_filter_size(image1_batch,image2_batch,power_factors,filter_size):
      shape1= image1_batch.shape[1:-1]  
      shape2= image2_batch.shape[1:-1] 
      if not(shape1[-3:-1][0]/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)) and shape2[-3:-1][0]/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)) >= filter_size):
            H = tf.math.reduce_min((shape1,shape2))
            suggested_filter_size = int(H/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)))
      else:
            suggested_filter_size = filter_size
      return suggested_filter_size
#Example: suggest_filter_size(field1, field2,power_factors = (0.0448, 0.2856, 0.3001, 0.2363, 0.1333), filter_size = 11)
```

Try this:

```py
H,W = 128,128  
field1 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, H, W, 1], minval=0, maxval=1) 
field2 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, H, W, 1], minval=0, maxval=1) 
filter_size = 11 #default from tf.image.ssim_multiscale
power_factors = (0.0448, 0.2856, 0.3001, 0.2363, 0.1333)  #default from tf.image.ssim_multiscale
#get a new filter_size from default values
new_filter_size = suggest_filter_size(field1, field2,power_factors,filter_size) 
#tf.image.ssim_multiscale would now work with new_filter_size
ms_ssim_score = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(img1=field1, img2=field1, max_val=1.0,filter_size=new_filter_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input arrays are most likely too small for the MS-SSIM calculation using the default setting.

From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/ssim_multiscale):

> power_factors: Iterable of weights for each of the scales. The number
>   of scales used is the length of the list. Index 0 is the unscaled
>   resolution's weight and each increasing scale corresponds to the image
>   being downsampled by 2. Defaults to (0.0448, 0.2856, 0.3001, 0.2363,
>   0.1333), which are the values obtained in the original paper.
>
> filter_size: Default value 11 (size of gaussian filter)

The default setting uses 5 2x downsampling operations a filter size of 11, so for a small image array, say 64x64, 3 2x downsampling reduce it to 8x8, which is smaller than the default kernel size 11.

Try this yourself:

```
N = 64 # change it to, say 512, then this works
a = np.random.randn(1, N, N, 1)
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
max_val = np.max(np.reshape(a, [-1]))
result = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(a, a, max_val)
```