# MS-SSIM in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, ssim

I want to use tf.image.ssim_multiscale for cacculate metric MS-SSIM and wrote this simple code. But it has error:

```
#(x_train.y_train),(x_test,y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
q1=train_images[0:10]
tf.image.ssim_multiscale(q1, q1, max_val=255)
InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: 10, 8, 8, 3
11
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33840#issuecomment-633715778) help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer my original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57127626/error-in-calculation-of-inbuilt-ms-ssim-function-in-tensorflow/62011055#62011055). The issue appears to be with assertion after spatial-dimension reduction. In  `_ssim_per_channel` , the `H` and `W` of images is [asserted](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L3524) against `filter_size` . Whereas in `ssim_multiscale`, [downsampling](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2b96f3662bd776e277f86997659e61046b56c315/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L3741) is performed `len(power_factors)-1` times.

Here are two workarounds:

1. Make sure that `filter_size` is small enough to calculate ssim values for all the four spatial-scales(excluding first scale) after downsampling within `ssim_multiscale`. Contrarily, ensure both `H` and `W`  of your image are big enough such that `H/(2**4) and W/(2**4) >= filter_size` .
2. Since downsampling is performed `len(power_factors)-1` times, you can also use lesser number of `_MSSSIM_WEIGHTS` or power_factors than default, which means `H/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)) and W/(2**(len(power_factors)-1)) >= filter_size` .

```py
field1 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, 64, 64, 1], minval=0, maxval=1)
field2 = tf.random.uniform(shape=[8, 64, 64, 1], minval=0, maxval=1) 
#Use smaller filter_size
ms_ssim_score = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(img1=field1, img2=field2, max_val=1.0,
                                         filter_size=4)
#Or use lesser number of power_factors
ms_ssim_score = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(img1=field1, img2=field2, max_val=1.0,
                                         power_factors=(0.0448, 0.2856, 0.3001),
                                         filter_size=11)
```